# How can i set a controller with a no empty constructor in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Let's say I have this:

```
public class selezioneTipoEventoForm {

    @FXML private Button eventoSportivoButton;
    @FXML private Button eventoMusicaleButton;
    @FXML private Button eventoTeatraleButton;
    @FXML private Button eventoCinemaButton;
    private formController cambiaForm;

    public selezioneTipoEventoForm(formController cambiaForm){
        this.cambiaForm=cambiaForm;
    }

    @FXML public void eventoSportivoButtonPressed(ActionEvent e){
        cambiaForm.mostraFormInserisciEvento(tipologiaEnum.SPORTIVO);
    }
```

This is my custom controller, now the FXML file when I bind the method to the button this error come up:

```
No controller specified for top level element
```

Because I want to set the controller later with my data so I didn't set the controller in the FXML file, in this case I need a  class called `formController`, and in this class I have this method:

```
private eventoSpecificoForm setControllerEventoSportivo(FXMLLoader loader,datiEventoController controllaDatiEvento) {
    try {
       eventoSportivoForm esf=  new eventoSportivoForm(controllaDatiEvento);
        Node root = loader.load();
        formAggiuntivo.getChildren().add(root);
        loader.setController(esf);
        return esf;
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return null;
}
```

There is a solution to this? It's freaking me out.

**EDIT:** This is the file fxml who gave me the error:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="370.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <JFXButton fx:id="eventoSportivoButton" buttonType="RAISED" layoutX="73.0" layoutY="59.0" onAction="#eventoSportivoButtonPressed" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #d9663f;" text="Evento Sportivo" textFill="WHITE">
         <graphic>
            <ImageView fitHeight="26.0" fitWidth="39.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../icons/icons8-soccer-ball-64.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </graphic>
      </JFXButton>
      <JFXButton fx:id="eventoMusicaleButton" buttonType="RAISED" layoutX="273.0" layoutY="59.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3fd9a5;" text="Evento Musicale" textFill="WHITE">
         <graphic>
            <ImageView fitHeight="26.0" fitWidth="39.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../icons/icons8-musical-64.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </graphic>
      </JFXButton>
      <JFXButton fx:id="eventoTeatraleButton" buttonType="RAISED" layoutX="73.0" layoutY="159.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3f78da;" text="Evento Teatrale" textFill="WHITE">
         <graphic>
            <ImageView fitHeight="26.0" fitWidth="39.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../icons/icons8-theatre-mask-64.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </graphic>
      </JFXButton>
      <JFXButton fx:id="eventoCinemaButton" buttonType="RAISED" layoutX="273.0" layoutY="159.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #da3e3e;" text="Cinema" textFill="WHITE">
         <graphic>
            <ImageView fitHeight="26.0" fitWidth="39.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../icons/icons8-film-reel-64.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </graphic>
      </JFXButton>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This line:

```xml
<JFXButton fx:id="eventoSportivoButton" buttonType="RAISED" layoutX="73.0" layoutY="59.0" onAction=**"#eventoSportivoButtonPressed**" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #d9663f;" text="Evento Sportivo" textFill="WHITE">
     <graphic>
```

'No controller specified for top level element'

Comment: You need to set the controller ***before*** calling `FXMLLoader.load()`. (Please note your code becomes easier to read, if you adhere to the java naming conventions, i.e. use type names that start with an uppercase letter.)

Comment: Thanks a lot(also for the naming conventions i'm still new to java), that was an idea, but the fxml continues to give me error so i didnt do it.

Comment: @JimMinor9 publish the error.

Comment: Edited with the file and error, i solved btw ,thanks to @fabian.